# How use Goal in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

In TurboPrologwe can use next construction:

```
goal:
  father('Tom', X).
```

How use same in SWI-Prolog?

Comment: Turbo Prolog is special here. Most other systems have `initialization/1` as directive.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall what `goal` does, I suggest to use the ISO-Prolog built-in [initialization/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28initialization%29/1):

> Call Goal after loading the source file in which this directive appears has been completed.

```
:- initialization((father('Tom', X), writeln(X))).
```

I've added a visualization of the value obtained - if any. Also some error handling should be added...

Answer (score 0):

And how we can call 2 or more Goal?

Next code call error:

```
:- initialization(
       (grandmother('Sarah', X), writeln(X)),
       (father('Tom', Y), writeln(Y))
    ).
```

Comment: Your code is essentially: `:- initialization(A,B).` Try `:- initialization((A,B)).` instead. Alternatively, you may want to give several `initialization` directives - bear in mind the order in which they are executed is "implementation defined". I.e. look up what your implementation says on it.